# How to set Title for cell using Dictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I want to use `NSDictionary` instead of cell Array.

Following is my code:

```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

         UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        //Add the Bg Image to the cell
         //Add the Label
         UILabel *cellTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 7, 300, 30)];
         [cellTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
         [cellTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
         [cellTitle setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
         [cellTitle setText:[[cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]             objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
         [cell.contentView addSubview:cellTitle];
         return  cell;

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *dictionary1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"ABC",@"Name",@"12",@"Age", nil];

NSDictionary *dictionary2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"DEF",@"Name",@"14",@"Age", nil];

NSDictionary *dictionary3 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"GHI",@"Name",@"16",@"Age", nil];

NSDictionary *dictionary4 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"JKL",@"Name",@"18",@"Age", nil];

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:dictionary1,dictionary2,dictionary3,dictionary4, nil];
```

Now in the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    //Add the Bg Image to the cell
     //Add the Label
     UILabel *cellTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 7, 300, 30)];
     [cellTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
     [cellTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
     [cellTitle setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
     [cellTitle setText:[[array objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"]];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:cellTitle];
     return  cell;

   }
```

also in the numberOfRowsInSection:

```
   -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section   
   {
       return [array count];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use newer syntax like this

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"key" : @"value", @"key2" : @"value2"};
NSDictionary *dict2 = @{@"key" : @"value", @"key2" : @"value2"};

NSArray *array = @(dict, dict2);
```